# Building a login with ASP.NET in VB

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I found a youtube video on building a website login with asp.net the problem is it is in C# but I have been converting it to VB when I ran the program I got this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web       request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:
```

```
or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

I know this means something is in C# but I can't find what it is. Here is the code.

```
       Imports System
       Imports System.Collections.Generic
       Imports System.Linq
       Imports System.Web
       Imports System.Web.UI
       Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
       Imports System.Data.SqlClient
       Imports System.Configuration



Partial Class Registration
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub Submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Submit.Click
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim insCmd As String = "Insert into Registration (Username, Password, EmailAddress, FullName, Country) values (@UserName, @Password, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country)"
    Dim InsertUser As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(insCmd, con)
    InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBoxUN.Text)
    InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxPass.Text)
    InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text)
    InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text)
    InsertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString())

    Try
        InsertUser.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("You have just launched a nuclear warhead and started WWIII seek shelter ASAP")

    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If (IsPostBack) Then


        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()

        Dim cmdStr As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration WHERE UserName='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'"

        Dim userExist As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdStr, con)

        Dim temp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString())
        con.Close()

        If temp = 1 Then
            Response.Write("Username already exist. Please choose another username")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

If you see anything please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try following the suggestions that VS gave you? If so, what happened?

Comment: try adding the debug true to the web.config file as VS suggested, that should help better locate the error.  otherwise make sure you have the RegconnectionString entry in your web.config file and that the SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration WHERE UserName= query returns something.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the only thing I would do is step through and make sure nothing has "No Value" that and i'm not familiar with that if statement setup, i'd be more comfortable with =true or not(condition) rather then isPostback, can't remember if the answer defaults to true but i'd look at those 2

Answer (score 0):

Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)

Can you replace the above code with

Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").toString())